# Make our application show in access and defaults

Tags: windows, registry, default-programs

We are developing our application to be a default e-mail program, and would like it to be one of the options in the Control Panel-> Add or Remove Programs-> Access and Defaults-> Custom-> Choose a default e-mail program: area. How is this done?

It's a rather simple registry change to add the application to the list in IExplore-> Tools -> Internet Options -> Programs -> E-mail:  But apparently this is not the list that is displayed in the Access and Defaults area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the msdn page for [Registering Programs with Client Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144109(VS.85).aspx), which is what you need to do. It's a few registry keys, and there is even a [sample for a mail client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144109(VS.85).aspx#sample_mail_program).

Comment: Thanks...I had actually tried adding those registry values, but had left out the InstallInfo key and values.  After adding those, works great.

InstallInfo 
      HideIconsCommand = command line
      ReinstallCommand = command line
      ShowIconsCommand = command line
      IconsVisible = 1